# signalR hub 2 connection fails using angular 5 and MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr-hub, angular5

i tried to make use of this post:
https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-chat-angular/
and make connection to signalR hub using angular 5. but when i run the project i see this message in console:

Error: Failed to start the connection. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
app.component.ts:24 Error while establishing connection :(

here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
  nick = '';
  message = '';
  messages: string[] = [];

  public getRealTime(): void {
    this._hubConnection
      .invoke('getRealTime')
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('/clockHub');

    this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));


    this._hubConnection.on('setRealTime', (time: string) => {
      alert(time);
    });
  }

}
```

and also code for hub class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;


namespace clockHub
{

        public class ClockHub : Hub
        {
            public void GetRealTime()
            {
                Clients.Caller.setRealTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
            }
        }

}
```

Thank You.

Comment: There is somthing strange with your code. Clockhub inside chathub   public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public class ClockHub : Hub
        {

Comment: oh, i just noticed what you mentioned and corrected it but i am receiving same error message. connection fails.

Comment: do send for test once only a normal string without special chars. Like:  Clients.Caller.setRealTime("Test"). Add breakpoint in client an check if this message will be sent

Comment: as you can see i simply put an alert in setRealTime method, but problem is that the connection fails in first place.